# Use .scss color variables in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I could create a scss class for the button and set the color there but that seems like extra work when all that scss class would do is set the color. My question is can I set the color somehow in the component without having to create and set a class to the component?

```
//my scss variables. They are in a _variables.scss file.
$t_light: #efefed;
$primary: #61B4C6;
$med_primary: #354063;
$dk_primary: #222f34;
$info: #647373;
$success: #52b173;
$warning: #d0a03b;
$danger: #f44336;

//something like this. This is in the Login.vue file.
<v-btn
    color="primary"
    @click="submit">Login
</v-btn>
```

Edit
Webpack

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .webpackConfig({
        output: { chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js?id=[chunkhash]' },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js',
                '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
            },
        },
    })
    .babelConfig({
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'],
    })
    .version();
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [article](https://css-tricks.com/getting-javascript-to-talk-to-css-and-sass/)  you need to export the sass variables as follows

```
$t_light: #efefed;
$primary: #61B4C6;
$med_primary: #354063;
$dk_primary: #222f34;
$info: #647373;
$success: #52b173;
$warning: #d0a03b;
$danger: #f44336;

:export{
tLight:$t_light,;
primary:$primary;
....
}
```

Then import the Sass file (`variables.scss`) file into JavaScript, giving you access to the variables defined in the file.

```
 import variables from './variables.scss';
```

in data property add the variables as :

```
data(){
  return{
    variables
  };
}
```

template

```
<v-btn
    :color="variables.primary"
    @click="submit">Login
</v-btn>
```

Comment: my webpack looks nothing like that one since I'm also using Inertia-vue, I will add the code in the question, I'm not sure where I would put what's in the article.

Comment: the article for javascript but you could adapt it to the Vue code

Comment: the `:export` doesn't work without the webpack configuration, and I don't know where to put it

Comment: you put it inside the .scss file where you're defining your variables, but you should configure your webpack

Comment: That's what I'm saying but I don't know where to add the code needed in the webpack, I added what I have in my webpack in the question above

Comment: in the webpack.config.js file

Comment: if you're working with vue-cli i think this is preconfigured

Comment: I tried this solution in VITE, but isn't working. Any suggestions?

Comment: It doesn't work according to this issue https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1279